# divisors of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I have a problem with an exercise.
I have the two following sentences I have to determine if they are true or false.

> If $a<b$ and the remainder of $b$ and $a$ divided by $c$ are equal then $c\mid(b-a)$
>
> If $a<b$ and the remainder of $b$ and $a$ divided by $c$ are equal then $c\mid b-a$

I think the first is true. But I can't understand what's the different when removing the brackets?

Thanks.

EDITED!
I was mistaken copying the questing. Sorry! Now its correct

Comment: There isn’t any difference when you remove the brackets. It’s the same thing.

Comment: I think the difference is how $c\mid b - a$ and $(c\mid b)-a$ but... does the latter make any sense? There is no difference when moving the brackets btw. It is like saying $c=b-a$ compared to $c=(b-a)$. They mean the same thing. But with your example, we replace $=$ with $\mid$. Thus, it is a trick question.... I think?

Comment: Looks like it is... And both are true...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is true even if you remove the hypothesis that $a<b$.

I also see no difference between the assertions.

Comment: I don't think this is true. The statements $b\equiv c \pmod a$ and $c\mid (b-a)$ are quite unrelated, aren't they?

Comment: @Claudius I don't understand your remark since the relation $b\equiv c\pmod a$ was nowhere mentioned in the original question.

Comment: But "the remainder of $b$ and $c$ divided by $a$ are equal" translates to $b\equiv c \pmod a$...

Comment: @Claudius I see. You are right. Post it as an answer.

Comment: It is fine if you correct your answer. I see no necessity for more than one answer.

Comment: @Claudius I have edited my answer. But if you wish to post it as your answer, go ahead and I will delete mine.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I was mistaken copying the question.

Comment: @maryum375 I have reverted my answer to its first version.